# dynamically handling metadata

Tags: metadata, dublin-core

I get data from the server to dynamically create a video gallery on the client. Those data contain metadata-related information such as contributor etc.

I have a standard snippet for dublin core data in my webpage like

```
    <meta name="DC.Source" id="videdsource" />
    <meta name="DC.Description" id="metadesv" />
    <meta name="DC.Creator" id="videdcreator" />
    <meta name="DC.Contributor" id="videdcontr" />
    //and so on, for all the dublin core elements...
```

Each time the users picks another video,I want to dynamically change the metadata values using a code like

```
document.getElementById("videdcreator").content=arrayvid[i];
```

This is not working. Because If I load the web page and look at the source code, the dublin core elements that are standard have a value , like

```
<meta name="DC.Rights" content="Copyright 2014"  />
```

but, the elements that I want to change dynamically, have no values, like

```
<meta name="DC.Contributor" id="videdcontr" />
```

How do I fix this?

What is the best practice to dynamically handle multimedia metadata on a webpage?

Thanks

Comment: Call me crazy, but the point of meta data is for help with loading the page prior to the content being loaded .. changing the head meta data after you have loaded the page kind of defeats the purpose doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to JS and to stackoverflow as well. Don't know if this is going to help you, but have you tried the following?

**Ex. 1**

- Have id's to your meta tags -- checked

  ```
  <meta name="DC.Source" id="videdsource" />
  <meta name="DC.Description" id="metadesv" />
  <meta name="DC.Creator" id="videdcreator" />
  ```
- The trigger

```
object.onclick=changeTags();
```

- JS function

  ```
  function changeTags(){
         $("#videdsource").attr("content","yourlink");
         $("#metadesv").attr("content","Coolest video");
         $("#videdcreator").attr("content","Chuck Norris");
      }
  ```

Does this help you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

This is was my mistake, because first of all, metadata dont support `id`.

But they have a name. So, in pure JS, I can do `getElementsByName` and then `setAttribute`

So the code is

```
//html part
<meta name="DC.Creator"/>
<button id="change" type="button">change it</button>


//javascript part
document.getElementById('change').onclick=myfunc;
var ha="ha";
function myfunc()
    {
    document.getElementsByName("DC.Creator")[0].setAttribute("content",ha);
    }
```

You can see your changes by doing "inspect element" on your browser

Credits go to the user named "geomagas" on this [Greek forum](http://www.insomnia.gr/topic/530307-%CE%B4%CF%85%CE%BD%CE%B1%CE%BC%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B7-%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1%CF%87%CE%B5%CE%B9%CF%81%CE%B9%CF%83%CE%B7-metadata-%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%BD-%CF%83%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use php and do something like

```
<meta name="DC.Creator" id="videdcreator" content="<?echo $arrayvid["vidcreator"][i];?>"/>
```